# How to find Duplicate selectors between multiple css files using stylelint

Tags: css, stylelint, csslint

I want to find duplicate selectors between multiple css files. i can't merge those files into single one. as i need to results for each file, which will be easy for removing duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible with stylelint as it operates on sources individually.